# What would be a good icon for representing "Stress"?

Tags: icon

I'm referring to mental stress - state of mental or emotional strain or tension resulting from adverse or demanding circumstances.

Comment: https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=stress&i=1760

Comment: A brain + alarm clock (like those old bell alarm clocks that you smack for "snooze" :P )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the situtation but genearlly speaking I think a lightening bolt striking through a brain (or possibily a heart for specificly emotional stress) would work quite well in most situations.

Comment: I like where you're heading with this but it could be mistaken for a stroke or a heart attack.

Answer (score 1):

Muller-Brockmann did some excellent designs for a sleeping medicine before. I couldn't find them online, but they are a book that I have  at home. Will take some pics and add them later.

Answer (score 1):

There is a notion of tensile stress in materials,
[image]

perhaps that would work?

Comment: How does that relate to emotional stress, care to explain?

Comment: It doesn't, really, but it is the same word. Lots of 'stress' can cause the material/person to break. The symbolism is similar to why we still use Floppy disks as icons to save on a computer - noone uses floppy disks anymore, but everyone understands the symbol.

Comment: Yes but floppies (floppys?) used to be used to save files, hence the connection. It's not the same as just using the same word.

Comment: Sure, but consider the other image with a light-bulb appearing above a persons head to indicate an idea - that never happens IRL. It is symbolism. The word 'stress' as a psychological term probably stems from the physical description above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a face with excess sweat drops, or a person sitting with their elbows on a desk with hands touching temples of the head. I like the above idea too.